# Segmentation fault using boost python and numpy

Tags: python, c++, numpy, boost

I have a `boost::python` library and am using numpy (*not* `boost::numpy`). My Python script uses my library and functions without any issue. However, when my script ends, numpy segfaults. I have tried to generate a MWE that shows the issue.

The following python script will segfault sometimes *after* finishing:

`test.py`

```python
import arrayTest

arr = arrayTest.getTestArray()

print(arr)
```

`pythonModule.cpp`

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
#include <numpy/ndarrayobject.h>

#include <vector>

namespace detail
{
    #if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
    inline void* init() 
    {
        import_array();
    }
    #else
    inline void init()
    {
        import_array();
    }
    #endif
}


boost::python::object getNPArray()
{
    using namespace boost::python;

    auto data = std::vector<double>(2*3*4);
    data.at(6) = 12;

    npy_intp shape[3] = { 2,3,4 };

    PyObject* obj = PyArray_New(
        &PyArray_Type, 
        3, 
        shape, 
        NPY_DOUBLE, 
        nullptr, 
        data.data(), 
        0, 
        NPY_ARRAY_FARRAY, 
        nullptr);

    handle<> handle( obj );

    numeric::array arr( handle );

    return arr.copy();
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(arrayTest)
{
    detail::init();

    using namespace boost::python;

    numeric::array::set_module_and_type(
            "numpy", 
            "ndarray");   

    def("getTestArray", &getNPArray);
}
```

To make it easy for you to compile I have also prepared a cmake script:

`CMakeLists.txt`

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6 FATAL_ERROR)

project("testArray")

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python3 REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs 3 REQUIRED)

# If you have your own findNumpy you can remove this part
find_package(PythonInterp 3)

if(PYTHON_EXECUTABLE)
    execute_process(
        COMMAND "${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}" -c "try:  import numpy; print(numpy.get_include(), end='')\nexcept:pass\n" OUTPUT_VARIABLE path)

    execute_process(
        COMMAND "${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}" -c "try:  import numpy; print(numpy.__version__, end='')\nexcept:pass\n" OUTPUT_VARIABLE version)

    find_path(PYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS numpy/ndarrayobject.h
        HINTS "${path}" "${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH}" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

    if(PYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS)
        set(PYTHON_NUMPY_VERSION ${version})
    endif()

else()
    message(SEND_ERROR "Python executable not found => Cannot determine numpy location.")
endif()

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(NumPy REQUIRED_VARS PYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS VERSION_VAR PYTHON_NUMPY_VERSION)
# end of findNumpy part

include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(libs 
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})

add_library(arrayTest SHARED pythonModule.cpp)
target_link_libraries(arrayTest ${libs})
set_target_properties(arrayTest
    PROPERTIES
        PREFIX "")
```

**Edit:**
In the python documentation I found the following:

> If data is passed to PyArray_NewFromDescr or PyArray_New, this memory must not be deallocated until the new array is deleted.

So maybe I need to manually delete the array? How do I do this?

Comment: Shouldn't `inline void* init()` return something?

Comment: `import_array()` is a macro somewhere in the numpy headers that includes a return statement.